# How to download this data using R/Python

Tags: python, r, web-scraping

I was trying to download data from below link:

[Link](https://www.nseindia.com/products/dynaContent/common/productsSymbolMapping.jsp?symbol=NIFTYEES&segmentLink=3&symbolCount=1&series=ALL&dateRange=%20&fromDate=01-06-2019&toDate=20-06-2019&dataType=PRICEVOLUMEDELIVERABLE)

**Below is my R code-**

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
readHTMLTable(getURL("https://www.nseindia.com/products/dynaContent/common/productsSymbolMapping.jsp?symbol=NIFTYEES&segmentLink=3&symbolCount=1&series=ALL&dateRange=+&fromDate=01-06-2019&toDate=20-06-2019&dataType=PRICEVOLUMEDELIVERABLE"))
```

This fails to download data onto my R console.

**Python code**

```
import http.client
connection = http.client.HTTPSConnection("www.nseindia.com")
connection.request("GET", "/products/dynaContent/common/productsSymbolMapping.jsp?symbol=NIFTYEES&segmentLink=3&symbolCount=1&series=ALL&dateRange=+&fromDate=01-06-2019&toDate=20-06-2019&dataType=PRICEVOLUMEDELIVERABLE")
res = connection.getresponse()
res.read()
```

This also failed to fetch any data.

Any help to download this data will be helpful

Comment: Well the link itself also doesn’t work, and yields HTTP status code 405. Does it work for you? If so, this suggests you need to send along an authentication cookie.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to extract from the webpage? Does it require any authentication to access? What is your code output?

Comment: I am getting 405 error with both R and python. But initially, when I tried to open that link in browser I got results. However, with a new browser, I see same 405 error. So perhaps as you pointed out - may be an authentication issue